# Volley doesn't pass the params?

Tags: android-studio, server, retrofit, android-volley, android-networking

I want to increment +1 each time and add it to the server SQL database. But problem is that below code runs only one time, rest of the +1 is not added to the server. I have checked many answers but none of them worked for me, so I ask about it. So can anybody tell me what mistake I am making on the code? Actually I'm new to volley so your detail guide would help me learn better.

My code Android Studio

```
 queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

         request = new StringRequest(StringRequest.Method.GET, "http://alfaazshayaristatus.com/apps/alfaaz/upload.php?id=" + id, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                Toast.makeText(ImageViewActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                Toast.makeText(ImageViewActivity.this, ""+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        );

        queue.add(request);
```

My Php

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];
$response = array();


     $insert = $db->query("UPDATE AlfaazStatus SET views=views+1 WHERE id=$id");
            if($insert){


                $message = "The file id ".$id." add +1 Like";


$success = true;

            }else{


$success = false;

                $message = "File upload failed, please try again.";
            }




$response["success"] = $success;
$response["message"] = $message;

header('Content-Type:Application/json');

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try add resize to images by using this  ?

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load(imageUrl)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                        .error(R.drawable.error)
                        .resize(screenWidth, imageHeight)
                        .fit.centerCrop()
                        .into(imageView);
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: the question changed dear, but yeah, I have used this method for the old question and it worked for me. Thank you but can you look at this updated question